# Grouping with condition in RStudio

Tags: r, conditional-statements, grouping

Good morning everyone, I have a csv file (df2.csv) with several variables, as illustrated below (just for example):

```
CLASSE  Variables   Terms   Number    
1       DAT_1    20160701q   5    
1       DAT_1    20160802q   2    
1       DAT_1    20160901q   1    
1       DAT_2    20161001q   1    
1       DAT_2    20161201q   2    
1       DAT_2    20170301q   3    
2       DAT_1    20161001q   1    
2       DAT_1    20161201q   2    
2       DAT_1    20170301q   1
```

I want for each class (1 or 2 in this case), for each distinct date variable, if the number of individuals is less than 3, to group individuals with the next date. If I have a period of more than 3 individuals, in this case, I want to have a date like '20160701q-20160901q' instead of 20160701q and 20160901q separately. In this case, we group two dates or more to get a period of more than 3 individuals, and if the next date of the class has less than 3 individuals, we will group this date with the period before also.
I started whit this code

```
for (n in df2$CLASSE){
  for (k in df2$Variables){
    for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
      if (df2$Number[i]<3){
        rempl_date=paste(df2$Terms[i],df2$Terms[i+1], sep="-")
        df2$Terms[i]<-rempl_date
        next  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work, I want to have this one after grouping:

```
CLASSE  Variables   Terms              Number
1       DAT_1    20160701q               5
1       DAT_1    20160802q-20160901q     3
1       DAT_2    20161001q-20161201q     3
1       DAT_2    20170301q               3
2       DAT_1    20161001q-20170301q     4
```

I don't know what I must change else if you can help me, I hope I was clear. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R solution:

1. define custom function for grouping

```
f <- function(v, th = 3) {
  k <- 1
  r <- c()
  repeat {
    if (length(v)==0) break
    ind<-seq(head(which(cumsum(v)>=th),1))
    if (sum(v)<2*th) {
      r <- c(r,rep(k,length(v)))
      v <- c()
    } else {
      r <- c(r,rep(k,length(ind)))
      v <- v[-ind]
    }
    k <- k+1
  }
  r
}
```

2. then use `aggregate` + `ave`

```
dfout <- subset(aggregate(Terms~.,
                          within(within(df,grp <- ave(Number,Classe, Variables, FUN = f)),
                                 Number <- ave(Number,Classe,Variables,grp,FUN = sum)),
                          c),
                select = -grp)
```

3. format the `dfout` to the desired style by using `order`

```
dfout <- dfout[order(dfout$Classe,dfout$Variables),]
```

**Output**

```
> dfout
  Classe Variables Number                           Terms
3      1     DAT_1      5                       20160701q
4      1     DAT_1      3            20160802q, 20160901q
1      1     DAT_2      3            20161001q, 20161201q
5      1     DAT_2      3                       20170301q
2      2     DAT_1      4 20161001q, 20161201q, 20170301q
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Classe = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    Variables = c("DAT_1", "DAT_1", "DAT_1", "DAT_2", "DAT_2", 
    "DAT_2", "DAT_1", "DAT_1", "DAT_1"), Terms = c("20160701q", 
    "20160802q", "20160901q", "20161001q", "20161201q", "20170301q", 
    "20161001q", "20161201q", "20170301q"), Number = c(5L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to concatenate the contents in `Terms`, try the code below

```
dfout <- subset(aggregate(Terms~.,
                          within(within(df,grp <- ave(Number,Classe, Variables, FUN = f)),
                                 Number <- ave(Number,Classe,Variables,grp,FUN = sum)),
                          FUN = function(v) ifelse(length(v)==1,v,paste0(c(v[1],v[length(v)]),collapse = "-"))),
                select = -grp)

dfout <- dfout[order(dfout$Classe,dfout$Variables),]
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Classe Variables Number               Terms
3      1     DAT_1      5           20160701q
4      1     DAT_1      3 20160802q-20160901q
1      1     DAT_2      3 20161001q-20161201q
5      1     DAT_2      3           20170301q
2      2     DAT_1      4 20161001q-20170301q
```

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding : thank you i tried your answer, how I can concatenate the content of the "Terms" variable to take the first and the last element to have a period like: 20160802q-20160901q  ??

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding : i found it thanks for you i adapted now the code to other cases of data

Comment: @Abdel_El Please see my update. If you think my answer is helpful, please feel free to upvote/ accept it, thanks!

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding thanks it's exactly what I'm searching ;-)

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding, just in the function (sum(v)<6) : why you choose 6 ? for me I try it in other case but it kept me some cases with less than 3 individuals in some periods, what do you think?

Comment: @Abdel_El It is twice of the threshold, i.e., `3` in your post. I updated function `f` in my answer, so you can change the threshold according to your needs

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding : sometimes the last row of the table is missing in the grouping like mentioned by Ronak Shah below : and the codes left the last row with less than 3 individuals, i tried the codes of Ronak Shah but it gave me some errors ...

Comment: @Abdel_El What do you mean by " the last row of the table is missing in the grouping"? In my function `f`, if the sum of leftover is less than `3`, then they will be added up to the previous group, so nothing will miss

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding : what happens in some cases, when the two lines have 4 and 2 individuals there is no regrouping which is done in this case to have a period of 6 individuals even if 2 <3 normally, and sometimes the last line of a variable of a class with 2 individuals remains alone instead of being grouped with the front line of the same variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210240/discussion-between-abdel-el-and-thomasiscoding).

Comment: @Abdel_El If I understand correctly, do you mean that, for instance, `v <- c(1,2,3,2)` will be grouped into `v <- c(3,3,2)`, where the last one remains there even though it is less than 3. Am I right? In that case, what you can do is to replace `sum(v)<2*th` by `length(ind)==0` for the condition of second `if` statement in function `f`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `MESS::cumsumbinning` function here to create groups until a threshold is reached.

```
library(dplyr)
thresh <- 3

temp <- df %>%
         group_by(CLASSE, Variables, 
                  group = MESS::cumsumbinning(Number, thresh)) %>%
         summarise(Terms = if(n() > 1) 
                           paste(first(Terms), last(Terms), sep = "-") else Terms,
                   Number = sum(Number)) %>%
         select(-group)
```

This returns :

```
temp
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   CLASSE, Variables [3]
#  CLASSE Variables Terms               Number
#   <int> <chr>     <chr>                <int>
#1      1 DAT_1     20160701q                5
#2      1 DAT_1     20160802q-20160901q      3
#3      1 DAT_2     20161001q-20161201q      3
#4      1 DAT_2     20170301q                3
#5      2 DAT_1     20161001q-20161201q      3
#6      2 DAT_1     20170301q                1
```

To combine the last row, we can do :

```
n <- nrow(temp) 
if(temp$Number[n] < 3) {
   temp$Terms[n-1] <- sub("-.*", paste0('-', temp$Terms[n]), temp$Terms[n -1])
   temp$Number[n-1] <- sum(temp$Number[n-1], temp$Number[n])
   temp <- temp[-n,]
}


#  CLASSE Variables Terms               Number
#   <int> <chr>     <chr>                <int>
#1      1 DAT_1     20160701q                5
#2      1 DAT_1     20160802q-20160901q      3
#3      1 DAT_2     20161001q-20161201q      3
#4      1 DAT_2     20170301q                3
#5      2 DAT_1     20161001q-20170301q      4
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i try it in this other case (below), but it gave me groups with 2 individuals , maybe the is some thing to change in codes                                                                                  CLASSE Variables Terms Number
1 DAT_1 20160701q 1
1 DAT_1 20160802q 1
1 DAT_1 20160901q 2
1 DAT_1 20160902q 2
1 DAT_1 20161001q 3
1 DAT_1 20161002q 1
1 DAT_1 20161201q 1
2 DAT_2 20161001q 1
2 DAT_2 20161201q 2
2 DAT_2 20170301q 1

Comment: @Abdel_El The formatting is not clear in comments. It would be easy to understand if you update your post with the example.

Comment: the definition of "thresh <- 3" it makes me a grouping with just 2 individuals and for me the condition is to do the grouping until getting 3 individuals at least ? what do you think.

Comment: how can I do if I want to apply the code to combine the last row with the row before if the number of individuals is less than 3 but for each term in each class not just the last row of the dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite cumbersome solution I've created that does what you asked. I'm sure it can be optimized or that functions from other packages can be used.

Explanations are inserted into the code

```
# new dataframe
df_new <- data.frame(
  CLASSE = numeric(nrow(df2)),
  Variables = character(nrow(df2)),
  Terms = character(nrow(df2)),
  Number = numeric(nrow(df2)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# temporary dataframe
temp_df <- data.frame(
  CLASSE = numeric(0),
  Variables = character(0),
  Terms = character(0),
  Number = numeric(0),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

temp_sum <- 0
present_row_temp_df <- 1
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  # if the row doesn't have to be grouped, just paste it in the new dataframe
  if (df2$Number[i] >= 3){
    df_new[i,] <- df2[i,]
    next
  }
  # if the row has to be grouped, add it to a temporary dataframe
  if (df2$Number[i] < 3){
    temp_df[present_row_temp_df,] <- df2[i,]
    temp_sum <- temp_sum + df2$Number[i]
    present_row_temp_df <- present_row_temp_df + 1
    # if the rows in the temporary dataframe need to be grouped now
    if(temp_sum >= 3){
      Terms_new <- paste(temp_df$Terms[1], temp_df$Terms[nrow(temp_df)], sep = "-")
      Number_new <- sum(temp_df$Number)
      df_new[i, c(1:3)] <- c(df2$CLASSE[i], df2$Variables[i], Terms_new)
      df_new[i, 4] <- Number_new
      # re-initialize temporary variables
      temp_df <- data.frame(
        CLASSE = numeric(0),
        Variables = character(0),
        Terms = character(0),
        Number = numeric(0),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
      temp_sum <- 0
      present_row_temp_df <- 1
    }
    # for the case in which the last row is not united with the previous rows
    if (i == nrow(df2) & df2$Number[i] < 3){
      Terms_new <- paste(stringr::str_extract(df_new$Terms[i-1], "^[^-]*"), df2$Terms[i], sep = "-")
      Number_new <- df_new$Number[i-1] + df2$Number[i]
      df_new[i, c(1:3)] <- c(df_new$CLASSE[i-1], df_new$Variables[i-1], Terms_new)
      df_new[i, 4] <- Number_new
      df_new[i-1,] <- c("0", "0", "0", 0)
    }
  }
}

# filter only relevant rows
df_new <- df_new[df_new$Number != 0,]
```

Result:

```
df_new

#CLASSE Variables               Terms Number
#     1     DAT_1           20160701q      5
#     1     DAT_1 20160802q-20160901q      3
#     1     DAT_2 20161001q-20161201q      3
#     1     DAT_2           20170301q      3
#     2     DAT_1 20161001q-20170301q      4
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but in other cases, it merges the classes, it takes some individuals from the class 1 and other individuals from class 2 instead of doing the grouping by terms by classes ?

Comment: @Abdel_El yeah you're right, it works for the sample data but it doesn't generalize well. Sorry for not answering your problem correctly